# Visual Basic 6 Bytecode Specification

Tags: vb6, bytecode, specifications, vm-implementation

Where can I find a list of official and unofficial Visual Basic 6 specifications that can allow me to, say, fully interpret the contents of a VB6 EXE file and analyze them, or interpret them on my own, instead of using `MSVBVM60.DLL`?

Something like the specification of the virtual machine and its language.

Things such as opcodes, instructions, mnemonics, whether it uses one or more stacks, stack pointers, registers, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't help much anyway really.  Even when compiled to native code much of it consists of calls back into the runtime for heavy lifting, much as compiled C++ does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VB6 can be compiled to p-code or native code.

- Native code is just native 8086 family machine code. I suppose that's a public standard. It's not very malleable.
- Here's a link about [p-code](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/P-Code-Implementation)